# Parse.com hosting a php script prompts download instead of executing

Tags: php, parse-platform

I uploaded a PHP script on public directory at parse.com cloud using the parse tool. Whenever I access the script URL, a download prompt appears to download that script file, instead of executing that script.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it so that it executes the PHP?

Comment: Titles that include wording like "not working" offer no summarized insight into the problem and are less likely to attract views. Be as specific and summarized as possible in your title.

Try to ask a question in your body even if you feel like it's already obvious. It helps others hone in the specific question your trying to get answered.

A little more effort in formatting will go a long way in showing others that you're making an effort to communicate clearly and effectively.

Comment: Is php installed there?

Comment: Maybe their PHP is configured to use only `<?php` while you are using `<?`. See [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com Doesn't support PHP. This is where I found the information.

https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-hosting-supports-html-file-with-embedded-php-code

Comment: Correct. You should convert your PHP script to equivalent JavaScript and upload it as a CloudCode function instead.